# Is there any ajax event available for datatable as columnEdit in primefaces.

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there any ajax event available for  datatable as columnEdit in primefaces. I want to edit the datatable column when i press the any symbol(edit icon or checkbox or radio button) in the column header.Is there any way to do that.

Comment: Do you want to edit the Header only ?!

Comment: No I want to edit the body

Comment: the body of data table !! Do you want to edit a row(s) ?

Comment: yes i want to edit the row of the column which i select ...

Comment: I don't think so. Only javascript/query action (maybe) can save you.

Comment: Is [this link](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/edit.xhtml) your looking for Dude !